# cvtcolor in Cv2 - no attribute

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy, rgb

I'm writing a program to collect a series of images from a USB microscope and generate an average as a way of denoising.  I'm having to convert the image into a numpy array, sum the pixels then divide before converting back to an image.

Somewhere along the line the channels get mixed so my output is BGR not RGB, I'm trying to use cvtcolor to rectify that but get the error:

> ---> 55  RgbImage = cv2.cvtcolor(ave_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
>       56  return RgbImage
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cvtcolor'

Presumably cvtcolour isn't being imported from CV2 but I can't see why. Here's the relevant code sections.

Lastly, although the averaging works fine, is there a more elegant way to do it? I need a simple mean not a weighted average.

```
import os, numpy, PIL
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import time
frameaverage=5


 def average_image():

 arr=numpy.zeros((h,w,3),numpy.float)
 # Build up average pixel intensities as floating
 for im in xrange(frameaverage):
    camera_capture = get_image()
    imarr=numpy.array(camera_capture,dtype=numpy.float)
    arr=arr+imarr/frameaverage
 # Round values convert to 8-bit integer
 arr=numpy.array(numpy.round(arr),dtype=numpy.uint8)
 ave_image=Image.fromarray(arr,mode="RGB")
 RgbImage = cv2.cvtcolor(ave_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 return RgbImage
```

Comment: from precision point of view (although it does not really matters if you average only on 5 images) it is best to define 'arr' to be of type double or uint16/32/64 (depends on the number of averaged images). replace 'arr=arr+imarr/frameaverage' by 'arr=arr+imarr' and after the loop do 'avg = arr/frameaverage'

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cvtcolor'` is because of a **typo**. it's `cvtColor` with a capital C in there. **voting to close**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In cv2 function cvtcolor renamed to `cvtColor`. So you should use  `RgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(ave_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: cheers, that fixed the original error but produced another about the object not being a numpy array so I had to tweak it a little bit more     >RgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(arr,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
     >ave_image=Image.fromarray(RgbImage,mode="RGB")